# is IPN is available in payflow pro?

Tags: java, paypal, payflowpro

is paypal notificaiton [IPN] available for payflow pro sdk too?
   -What if recurring payment fails?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PayPal confirms that there is no IPN service available for PayFlow pro Recurring Payment.  You can use INQUIRY action to know profile status and the payments details.

Comment: can you please provide reference?

Comment: Please check this link, on page 29 https://www.paypalobjects.com/webstatic/en_US/developer/docs/pdf/pp_payflowpro_recurringbilling_guide.pdf